# Node js route not working,always shows cannot post

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have referred few answers on stackoverflow too,but still not working. When i use app.post function in app.js with a function it works but when i put route inside it it doesnt work and postman says cannot post. It was working fine 1 day ago.
Here is the code of app.js

```
let express=require("express");
let app=express();
let signuproute=require("./routes/signup");
app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
console.log("server started");

});

app.get("/",function(req,res){

  console.log("home page called");
  res.send({message:"Thanks for calling home page"});
});

app.post("/signup",signuproute);
```

the above signup route doesnt work but when i directly pass the function in it like

```
 app.post("/signup",function(req,res){ console.log("signed up"); });
```

It prints signed up on console. So Why does the route is not working.

Here is my signed up route, signup.js:

```
let express=require('express');
let router=express.Router();

console.log("Signup called");
router.get("/",function(req,res){

});
router.post("/",function(req,res,next){

  res.send({message:"thank you for signing up"});
});
module.exports=router;
```

Comment: I think it should be `app.use("/signup",signuproute);`

Comment: i was using app.use only mate, but in that way it was always calling only the home directory.Then i saw get and post being used directly in app.js in few examples too.

Comment: Well, I just try your code and only change `app.post("/signup"` to `app.use("/signup"` and it worked.

Comment: how do you test your call? do you open `/signup` or `/signup/` ?

Comment: i open /signup obviously on postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you already defined a post route handler in `routes/signup.js` file. Hence it is have no sense to write `app.post(router.post(function (req, res, next) {})`.

You have to use `app.use` function as stated [in express.JS API references](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.use).

Think about `app.use('/signup', signupRoute)` as `/signup` namespace for common SignUp functionality. For example in the future you may want to reuse SignUp functionality with `/user/create` route like this `app.use('/user/create', signupRoute)`.

Here is how your example should looks like:

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let signupRoute = require("./routes/signup");

app.listen(3000, function(req, res) {
  console.log("server started");
});

app.get("/",function(req,res){  
  console.log("home page called");
  res.send({message:"Thanks for calling home page"});
});

app.use("/signup",signupRoute);
```

Comment: this worked for me, because i kept homepage or "/" with get and changed "/signup" with use. I noticed when i made both of them with app.use, everytime after that i called signup endpoint ,still home was being called. why its like that even after mentioning sigup at end while calling?

Comment: is it becoz when we call something in app.js itself we have to give function there, and when using route we have to use app.use. I am little new to node js.

Comment: This is due to how `app.use` works. If you pass just a function handler for `app.use` it will be called for every request. That the main difference between `app.get` or `app.post` and `app.use`. Why `app.use('/sugnup', signupRoute)` not called for every request? Because in `signup.js` you defined `router.get('/', handlerFn)` and `router.post('/', handlerFn)` which will trigger only for get and post requests. If you would like to understand this concept deeply you need to read guides for [Epress.JS](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). I hope it help.

Comment: thanks again mate @shvetsovdm i have accepted your answer for clear explanation ! :)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases `app.post ('/signup')` and `app.get ('/')`, use the `app.use ('/signup')` and `app.use ('/home')`
As you are using separate route file for signup routin, also use one for home routing.

```
let express=require("express");
let app=express();

let signuproute = require("./routes/signup");
let homePageRoute = require("./routes/homePageRoute"); // define a home page route 

app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
console.log("server started");

});

app.use("/signup", signuproute);
app.use("/home", homePageRoute); // use created home page route
```

Answer (score 0):

router.post already contain a post method in this case use app.post instead of app.use method.

```
app.use('/signup',signuproute);
```

The Signup route contains a whatever method you written in signup.js that all accessible in /signup route.